# String... in Java

Tags: java, android

I was reading a tutorial on Vogella, and I noticed the notation String... being used in a method declaration. I tried googling it without success. Can somebody explain what it is?

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
  String response = "";
  for (String url : urls) {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
      InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
      String s = "";
      while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        response += s;
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Look up `varargs`. What did you try to google?

Comment: String... will represent multiple strings as an array.

Comment: _"String triple dot java"_ on Google would give you the solution much more faster than asking here. :)

Comment: Look on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: Thanks guys! I just googled "String..."

Comment: var args baby ..introduced in Java 1.5

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword "varargs" guys! Good to know this exists.